# Distance function on unit ball from a closed set is lower semi-continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

While solving exercises from the book [Real Analysis by Carothers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521497566), I have read about lower [semi-continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) (Exercise of chapter 5, Problem 32 on page 67). I have managed to solve the problem but came to know another example of lower semi-continuous function from my teacher. But I am having problem to actually prove that. Please help me. Thnx in advance.

Here is the problem.

> Let $(X, || . ||)$ be normed linear space with the naturally induced metric $d(x,y)=||x-y||$ on $X$. Let $B=\{x\in X \mid ||x|| <1\}$ and $Y$ be a closed subspace of $X$. Define $f:B\to \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=d(x,Y)$ which is the distance of $x$ from the subspace $Y$. Prove that $f$ is lower semi-continuous.

Now in order to solve the problem I thought to show $S_{\alpha} =\{x\in B \mid f(x)=d(x,Y)\le \alpha \}$ to be closed for all $\alpha \in \mathbb R$

Now in order to do that we may assume $\alpha \ge 0$ as otherwise for $\alpha <0$ the set $S_{\alpha}=\phi$ is automatically closed.

But after that I am completely stuck. I can not find a way to show that if a sequence $(x_n)$ in $S_{\alpha}$ converges to $x$ then $x$ must be in $S_{\alpha}$.

Am I on the right track or some other approach will be easy for this?

One more thing, I think the set $B$ must play a role here but I can not figure it out what it is.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry..It was a typo. I have fixed it. I have tried with equality but can not get it.

Comment: why don't use the $\epsilon$-\delta$ definition? it is just the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: $S_\alpha$ is not closed in $X$, at best in $B$. For example $X=\mathbb R^n$, $Y=\{ 0 \}$, then $S_\alpha = B$ for any $\alpha \ge 1$.

Comment: @user251257 yes I see the example. But I have not understood why it is happening and hence what should I do to solve it. I have also commented after your comments in the answer by Crostul. Please help me to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your function $f$ to the whole space $X$ ($f(x)= d(x,Y)$). If $f$ is lower semicontinuous on $X$, it will be so on every of its subspaces, in particular on $B$.

I show that $X \setminus S_{\alpha}$ is open.

Forall $x \in X \setminus S_{\alpha}$ I want to find some open ball centered at $x$ which is contained in $X \setminus S_{\alpha}$. But how to find the radius of this ball? Well, you have $f(x) > \alpha$ so write
$$f(x) = \alpha + 3 \varepsilon$$
I show that $B_x(\varepsilon) \subset B \setminus S_{\alpha}$. Suppose by contradiction this is not the case. Then there exists some $z \in B_x(\varepsilon) \cap S_{\alpha}$. Since $d(z,Y) \le \alpha$ there exists $y \in Y$ such that $d(z,y) < \alpha + \varepsilon$. And now you get
$$\alpha +3\varepsilon = d(x,Y) \le d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y) < \varepsilon + \alpha + \varepsilon$$
a contradiction.

PS: Note that this argument works for every metric space. If you have any metric space $X$, and any subset $Y \subset X$, then the map $x \mapsto d(x,Y)$ is lower semicontinuous.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice answer. I got it now.

Comment: why isn't $x$ on the boundary of $B$?

Comment: @user251257 I don't work with $B$ anymore. I don't care about $B$, none about its boundary. So I don't get the point of your comment.

Comment: you need to change $S_\alpha$ to $\{ x\in X \mid d(x, Y) \le \alpha \}$. Otherwise the $S_\alpha$ in OP is only closed in $B$ not in $X$

Comment: @user251257 OK, I skipped this redefinition thinking that it was obvious.

Comment: I am not sure that OP knows the difference, as how the question was stated.

Comment: @user251257 I am really sorry. I can not understand the difference. Will you please help me? And in that case how should I proceed? Please help. Thnx in advance

Comment: @usermath for example $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb R$, but closed in the topological subspace $(0,1)$ (as it is the complete space). Your function $f$ is defined on $B$, so you only need to show that your $S_\alpha$ is closed in $B$. It is in general not closed in $X$.

Comment: @user251257 Ok I understand. Then at what point the above proof will go wrong? or it will work by just considering $B$ instead of $X$?

Comment: @usermath at $B_x(\epsilon) \subset B\setminus S_\alpha$, you need to understand $B_x(\epsilon)$ is a ball in $B$, that is $B_x(\epsilon) = \{ \tilde x \in B \mid d(x,\tilde x) < \epsilon \}$.

Comment: @usermath just an aside: using the triangle inequality you can easily show that $x \mapsto d(x, Y)$ is Lipschitz continuous on $X$. This whole approach with $S_\alpha$ is more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @user251257 yes I got it. In the above proof it is shown that $B_x(\epsilon)\cap S_{\alpha}=\phi$ But we still have to show that this ball goes inside $B$. Am I correct?

Comment: @user251257 And now I donot understand why Lipschitz continuity will imply lower semi-continuity. Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: @user251257 In order to show $B_x(\epsilon) \subseteq B$ if I take $u \in B_x(\epsilon) $ then $||u||=||u-x+x||\le ||u-x||+||x||< 1+\epsilon$ now how can I make it less than 1 so that $u\in B$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28999/discussion-between-user251257-and-usermath).

Comment: @user251257 Ok.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a correct answer. This is rather a different approach / aside. It is however kind of self-defeating, as the exercise is obviously about the characterization of semi continuity by sublevel sets.

I claim:

> For any non empty subset $Y\subseteq X$ the mapping $f:X\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = \operatorname{dist}(x, Y)$ is Lipschitz continuous.

**Proof:**
Let $x, \tilde x \in X$. Then, for every $y\in Y$ we have
$$ d(x,y) - d(\tilde x, x) \le d(\tilde x, y) \le d(x,y) + d(\tilde x, x) $$
by triangle inequality.
By taking the infimum for $y\in Y$, we obtain
$$ \operatorname{dist}(x, Y) - d(\tilde x, x) \le \operatorname{dist}(\tilde x, Y) \le \operatorname{dist}(x, Y) + d(\tilde x, x). $$
By subtracting $\operatorname{dist}(x, Y)$ and taking the absolute value, it follows
$$ | \operatorname{dist}(\tilde x, Y) - \operatorname{dist}(x, Y) | \le d(\tilde x, x), $$
that is, $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

**Notes:**

- Since $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, it is also continuous, and also (upper and lower) semi continuous. 
  Also the restriction of $f$ on $B$ is Lipschitz continuous and so on...
- Thus, the set $\{ x\in X \mid f(x) \le \alpha \}$ is closed for every $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. In particular $S_\alpha$ is closed in $B$.